# How to pass value to twig in Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to have inputs with customized labels (based on other entity attribute).

```
private $kilos_maxlim;
private $precio;
```

I set the values of `$kilos_maxlim` in the constructor of the class. So, I have that field filled. I want to show an input of `$precio` but with the label based on the value of `$kilos_maxlim`.

I have this input field in the classtype:

```
->add('precio', null, array(
    'attr' => array('autofocus' => true),
    'label' => 'label.precio',
))
```

How can I pass the value without being an input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work as simple as this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    // get the actual entity
    $entity = $builder->getData();

    // set the value as the label
    $builder->add('precio', null, array(
        'label' => 'label.precio ' . $entity->getKilosMaxlim(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: It throws: Call to a member function getKilosMaxlim() on a non-object. But when I dump the $entity it seems to be the right class type.

Comment: I have this in configureOptions method: $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\TarifaPeso',
        )); which is the right class too

Comment: When you call `var_dump($entity);` after `$entity = $builder->getData();` and it shows the correct class with the correct values, but `$entity->getKilosMaxlim()` doesn't work, it seems that there's a typo in `$entity->getKilosMaxlim()`.

Comment: Thanks! Finally what I've done is to add and eventListener with POST_SET_DATA and modify the label once the form is set and it works! Thanks!!!

Comment: That's another way to go.